# Total pairwise costs in a weighted undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

Consider that we have a weighted undirected graph where, for any two vertices, there is a unique path that connects them. There are `n` vertices and `n - 1` edges and the cost of each road is `c_i`.

Now, if every path that connects two given vertices has a certain cost that depends on the roads it passes by, how can we compute the total cost between all pairs of cities efficiently?

For example, the cost of each path can be the sum of the first road and the last road it passes by, or the sum of some power of the costs of each road it passes by, or the the maximum of the costs minus the minimum of the costs of the roads it passes by : Any formula that depends on the costs of the roads.

What algorithm to use in order to solve the problem efficiently ?

Comment: Your graph is a tree, and each edge is on a number of paths equal to the product of the numbers of vertices on each side.

Comment: keep track of max_total and min_total, both initially zero. Find the max weight edge in the graph and the number of paths it appears in. Add the product to max_total, delete the edge, and repeat (note that each of these splits the graph). Repeat the process for min edge weight. Now max_total is the sum across paths of the max edge weights, same for min. The difference is your answer.

Comment: It's O(size(component)) each time you split a component in 2, so worst case runtime is (number of splits) * (size of components being split) <= N^2. That's not great, but you only have 10k nodes so it should be good enough. Do you need something faster?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is something better than n^2, yeah.

Comment: FWIW the problem is much easier if you care about the sums along all the paths, which I think was the original problem. That's O(n).

Comment: I do care about the sums along all the paths but when the distance is defined as I say : "max - min", not the normal distance : sum of roads' costs. As you said, the latter is much easier. By the way, there must be a O(nlog(n)) solution or something like that.

Comment: @DaveGalvin's idea gives O(nlogn) solution if implemented with Euler tour trees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any path `p`, let `max(p)` and `min(p)` denote the max and min cost of the road it passes by.
Then `Total_cost = sum for all path p [max(p) - min(p)]`

Then `sum for all path p max(p)` can be found by the following way

```
Let G=(V,E) be the input graph, which should be a tree
Create a graph G' with vertices set V and no edges
Insert every edge in E to G' from lowest cost to hightest cost
```

Everytime you insert an edge `e`, it will connect two components `S, T`, and you can see that for every path `p` from `S` to `T`, `max(p) = cost(e)`
So you can find `sum for all path p max(p)` by summing them.
To connect two components efficiently, I think you can use the idea from Kruskal's algorithm.

Similarly, you can find `sum for all path p min(p)` and finally the total cost.

Answer (score 0):

For each edge `{u,v}` in your graph, by "removing" it, you get two disconnected components, let them be `U` and `V`.

This means, the edge `{u,v}` is a part of the path going from each node in `U` to each node in `V` in the original graph, and there are `|U| * |V|` such paths.

This means, the problem boils down to calculate the sizes of these sets.

One way to do it, is choose arbitrary vertex `r`, and "make it the root" by making all edges directed, form `r` outwards. You got yourself a rooted directed tree after you do it.

By traversing the tree once in linear time, you can now find the size of each subtree:

```
size(u) = sum { size(v} | v is a child of u}  + 1
```

After you have calculated the size of all subtrees, for each directed edge `(u,v)`, the sizes of original sets `|V|` and `|U|` are `size(v)` and `n-size(v)`.

Following these steps lead to linear time agorithm, with the following high level pseudo code.

```
Choose arbitrary r
Calculate size(u) for all nodes
sum = 0
for each edge (u,v) do:
  sum = sum + (cost(u,v) * (size(v) * (n-size(v))))
return sum
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But where do we use here the costs of the paths ? 
In order to make it easier to understand, let's take the case where the cost of each path is the maximum of the costs of the roads it passes by minus the minimum of the costs.

Comment: @Guru Each edge (u,v) is a part of a path between any two pairs of vertices, one in U and one in V. By calculating the sizes of U and V for each edge, `sum{cost(u,v) * |U| * |V|` | for all edges }` - is the sum of costs of all paths between each pair of vertices, because (u,v) contributes its cost to each path using it, and the number of such paths is `|U| * |V|`.

Comment: @Guru This assumes the standard definition of cost of a path - which is the sum of costs of the edges in it.

Comment: That's it .. That is not necessarily the definition I suppose, say we consider the cost of the path as the difference between the largest edge cost in the path and the least edge cost in the path, how to approach it then ?

Comment: @Guru That's going to depend on the distance metric. You probably can even encode NP-Hard problems in this if you allow enough freedom in choosing the distance metric.

Comment: Okay let's just consider the most interesting distance which is the one I just said : The difference between the largest edge cost in the path and the least edge cost in the path. Any idea how to solve this specific case ?

Comment: @Guru That's what I gave you in my latest comment to your question.